# is there another visual way of plotting big table values out of heat maps?

Tags: r, plot, heatmap

I have a data frame where the columns are the predictors of a variable and the rows different time periods. The data frame shows the percentage of times the predictors are significant for the different periods. I want to plot in a visual manner which ones are generally predictors and which ones are less. I have considered doing a heat map but the number of predictors is high (50) and the number of rows is small (3). So the plot is nice but I think it is too big in one dimension.

Is there another type of plot of visualizing this type of data in a nice manner? I think histograms have the same problem as heat maps for this case.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should try stack barplot with the time as your x axis. So you get 3 bars with the most important predictors enlighten.

Comment: Cool, thank you. That could be another way of facing the problem. I still think the plot would be too big in the X direction but it seems there is no other solution

Comment: You could also try to reduce the number of descriptors by a reduction model https://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/18/help-and-how-to/modeling-statistics/regression/supporting-topics/regression-models/model-reduction/